# date format issue string to java util date

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Date functions. i have a date as a string '03/10/2014' - month/date/year. i need to convert this like '10-MAR-14' util date format. How can i do this please help me.

i used 'MM/dd/yyy' and 'dd-MMM-yyy' formats.

```
    public static Date convertStringToDate(String aMask, String strDate)
            throws ParseException {
SimpleDateFormat df;
            Date date;
            df = new SimpleDateFormat(aMask);

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("converting '" + strDate + "' to date with mask '" + aMask + "'");
            }

            try {
                date = df.parse(strDate);
            } catch (ParseException pe) {
                //log.error("ParseException: " + pe);
                throw new ParseException(pe.getMessage(), pe.getErrorOffset());
            }

            return (date);
```

to do this. but gives me parse exception. Appreciate your help

but database column has the date-Month-year eg: 09-MAR-14. this does not give the result. i need to this conversion for hibernate criteria search. Database has results. but this conversion does not give the results.

Answer (score 4):

You missed a `y` in the expression, use `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

> The following code will make a method and use it your logic

```
       import java.text.ParseException;
       import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
       import java.util.Calendar;
       import java.util.Date;
       import java.util.GregorianCalendar;



public class ex {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
    String dateInString = "15-08-2014";
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf1.parse(dateInString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");   

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(date.getYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate());   
    System.out.println("Date :" + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

}
`

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. I need to add one day to the date. how can i fix that issue

Answer (score 0):

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    String format = dateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.print("format is:"+format);
```

Just follow this Simply

Answer (score -2):

It seems that the MSDN library has a format utility that can be downloaded to your project. See the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Sorry for downvote. The question was belongs to Java so MSDN library could help.